# Fastest way to exchange an array of double between two java programs

Tags: java, arrays, serialization, data-exchange

I need two separate java programs, running in separate JVMs to exchange numeric data as fast as possible through either a file stream (linux pipe) or over a network connection.

Every message is a double[] where the length of the array can vary from message to message. I would be interested what the fastest way to do this is, especially in a situation where both JVMs run on the same machine or the same hardware.

In a C-like language, this could be done by just aliasing the array to a byte buffer and transferring the byte buffer as is (plus a small header that will tell the recipient about the size of the array to create to take up the buffer). Is something similar possible with Java?

Comment: Json over network sockets looks pretty good to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over a socket connection, use an [`ObjectOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) to write the object directly to the stream, and use an [`ObjectInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) to deserialize at the other end.

Put simply, to send:

```
OutputStream out; // of socket
double[] array;

ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
oos.writeObject(array);
```

To receive:

```
InputStream in; // of socket
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(in);

double[] array = (double[])ois.readObject();
```

This uses java's built-in serialization library, which is as fast as possible. All primitives and arrays of primitives are serializable this way (as is anything that implements [`@Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)).

Comment: It occurred to me two minutes after posting the question that using Java's Object*Stream is probably among the fastest but also the most portable way to do this and it does not need any library! Thanks!